# The correct way to display images in a menu?

Tags: css

I'm curious.  I've made a drop down menu and in place of text, I've added an image. When I look at it, it doesn't seem *clean*. What is the correct way to write it in css?

For example -

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
<li id="one"><li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/bw1wxme/RjMmzv543/rollover-2.jpg"></span></a>
<ul>
<li class='last'><a href='#'><span>
<u>Hello</u>
</li>
<li><a href='#'><span>Website</span></a></li>

</span></a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
```

So instead of having, say, "ABOUT", I have -

```
<a href='#'><span><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/bw1wxme/RjMmzv543/rollover-2.jpg"></span></a>
```

Is this really bad CSS practice? I don't want to make a lifetime of bad CSS habits...

Comment: It's bad practice for blind users who will not be able to use screen reader technology to hear your menu options being read to them. Also, since the image aren't actually content they should be used as bg images to the links and not used inline.

Comment: Yes it is a bad practice - also validate your HTML since it's full of mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not great practice because, as Paulie_D said, vision-impared users viewing your site via screen-readers will not be able to use your menu properly.

Have a look at the [accessability](http://www.w3.org/standards/webdesign/accessibility) guidelines on w3c.org

A much better practice would be to create your menu with text, titles on links, and use css to style your hovers.